# subprocess.Popen not printing/running properly

Tags: python, bash, subprocess

I have a script that reads from external sensors (and runs forever), when I run it as `./zwmeter /dev/ttyUSB0 300` it behaves normally and prints output continuously to stdout. I am using bash on Ubuntu. I'd like to execute this command as part of a python script. I have tried:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE                                   
proc = Popen(['./zwmeter', '/dev/ttyUSB0', '300'], stderr=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)                                     
print proc.communicate()
```

but I get a program that runs forever without producing any output. I don't care about stderr, only stdout and have tried splitting up the printing but still with no success.

Thank you for any help you can provide!

Comment: does your command `./zwmeter /dev/ttyUSB0 300` runs forever? like `top` command?

Comment: Sortof, it never terminates, just keeps appending lines of text to stdout

Comment: i hope this link might help http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/672518-using-subprocess-non-terminating-command

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful but I actually want it to run forever and be able to communicate with it during that time. I found a good solution and posted the link as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem has to do with the process I'm calling not terminating. I found a good work around on this site:
http://eyalarubas.com/python-subproc-nonblock.html

Comment: [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/137096)